# How to place all files in python module to the same top level namespace?

Tags: python, namespaces

I have example python project with multiple files:

src/common.py:

```
def toint(x):
    return int(x)
```

src/foo1.py:

```
import common

def add(a,b):
    return common.toint(a) + common.toint(b)
```

src/foo2.py:

```
import common

def sub(a,b):
    return common.toint(a)-common.toint(b)
```

setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup (name = 'test_py_project',
       version = '1.0',
       author='Vladislav Tsendrovskii',
       description = 'test python modules',
       package_dir = {'': 'src'}
       )
```

Now I want to install this project. I run `python3 setup.py install --user` and it installs.

But it installs not in a way that I want.

When I try to use it, I have problems.

I can not do `import test_py_project.foo1`

But I can do `import foo1`

How should I modify my project, to place all stuff inside `test_py_project` namespace?

I have tried to google for solution. But I've failed(

Answer (score 0):

Reference the python docs https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references for creating modules and project directory format. E.g. Modulename/ModuleFiles.py and existence of a `__init__.py` and `__main__.py` files. From `__init__` you can `import *` or use relative/absolute imports.

Comment: Why are you referencing Python 2 documentation? I guess in 2022, nobody is using Python 2 anymore (hopefully) as it's end of life.

Answer (score 0):

> But I can do import foo1

As it seems, your Python can already find stuff inside the `src` folder.

If you want to make `test_py_project.foo1` work, create the necessary directory under `src` and move `foo1.py` there, so that you'll have `src/test_py_project/foo1.py`.

Then the import import `test_py_project.foo1` should work.